# Download the artifact with highest version number from Nexus

Tags: nexus, nexus3

I have a raw Nexus repository and would like to download the artifact with the highest version number. The version number has three components, semver style (1.2.3). Right now I do:

```
wget http://buildserver/service/rest/v1/search/assets/download?repository=foobar&name=com/mycompany/pcba_firmware*bin&sort=version
```

But this doesn't work as expected, it just returns some version but not the latest. Is there any way to get the highest version?

Comment: Raw repositories don't have the concept of "version", they consist of simple free format file paths.  There is no semantic coordinate information associated with files in them.

Comment: Is there any other type of repository that would be more suited? I'd like to archive binaries (firmware) that get produced by my Jenkins CI.

Comment: If you can package those firmwares in a format like rpm or apt, you could use the respective repositories format for example. But I doubt it is possible in that specific case. I believe you only solution is to list the available files using one the `/v1/search/assets` endpoint and then decide in your application the latest version to download based on the filename.